# How to reverse order the collection

Tags: backbone.js

Following collection is getting sorted based on date created in ascending order. How can it be reverse ordered in descending order?

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    urlRoot: '/records',
    comparator: function(model) {
        return new Date(model.get('datecreated')).getTime();
    }
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238127/sorting-by-date-with-underscore-js-or-just-plain-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return negative value from comparator.

```
comparator: function(model) {
  return -new Date(model.get('datecreated')).getTime();
}
```