# How can I sort a minimongo cursor by date?

Tags: javascript, sorting, meteor, minimongo

I would like to sort a minimongo cursor using a date field. It appears that `$orderBy` will be deprecated according to the mongoDB documentation (not that I know if it works with minimongo) and `sort()` does not seem to work.

Is there a way to sort a minimongo cursor using a date field or should I rely on plain Javascript/underscore ([Sorting by date with underscore.js or just plain JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238127/sorting-by-date-with-underscore-js-or-just-plain-js))?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `sort` is supported, I just didn't get the syntax right. It would look like this:

```
myCollection.find({},{sort:{date:1}); // for older to newer items
```

**Edit:** more generally, 1 is for ascending and -1 is for descending. (for future readers, as noted by @BlazeSahlzen in comments)

Comment: More generally, 1 is for ascending and -1 is for descending.