# Sorting an array by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How do you sort the following sample array by the dt (date) property of each object?

```
$scope.arr = [ 
    {test: 1, dt: 'March, 10 2016 14:55:00'},
    {test: 2, dt: 'February, 10 2013 14:25:00'},
    {test: 3, dt: 'August, 10 2015 14:55:00'} 
];
```

I tried _.sortBy($scope.arr, 'dt'), but that treats the date as a string and only does the sorting alphabetically. I tried converting the date into unix time and that actually complicated things as my real code is more complex.

Do you have any other suggestions of sorting the above in a descending order and show the result in a dropdown?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript), but I'll reopen it as it's not really sorting "by strings", but by dates. Maybe someone else has a more appropriate duplicate, because this has surely been asked before.

Comment: Anyway, you have to parse the dates to valid date objects, and then just do `$scope.arr.sort( (a,b) => { return parse(a) - parse(b) });` etc.

Comment: can you convert to ints and then compare?   Date.parse("March 21, 2012");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238127/sorting-by-date-with-underscore-js-or-just-plain-js ? That answer suggests creating a sort function and converting the string to a date.

Comment: The best thing you can do is create and array of months using keys as numbers and use that to compare with the array you have above.

Comment: See this related answer: **[Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date/26759127#26759127)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort with this call back which uses the Date equivalents for comparing:

```
$scope.arr.sort( (a, b) => new Date(a.dt) - new Date(b.dt) );
```

```js
$scope = {}; // for the snippet to work
$scope.arr = [ 
    {test: 1, dt: 'March, 10 2016 14:55:00'},
    {test: 2, dt: 'February, 10 2013 14:25:00'},
    {test: 3, dt: 'August, 10 2015 14:55:00'} 
];

$scope.arr.sort( (a, b) => new Date(a.dt) - new Date(b.dt) );

console.log($scope.arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Suffice it to sort on the second property casted as a Date Object :

```js
var arr = [
    {test: 1, dt: 'March, 10 2016 14:55:00'},
    {test: 2, dt: 'February, 10 2013 14:25:00'},
    {test: 3, dt: 'August, 10 2015 14:55:00'}
];

arr.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.dt) - new Date(a.dt));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: User wanted it to be in **descending*** order, so I flipped it and put it in a snippet so they could see the actual output.

Comment: Yes thanks Trasiva for having flipped the value in the comparator method

Answer (score 2):

As those aren't really valid dates, even if they can be parsed by some browser, you'd generally want to parse them properly and pass in numbers to `new Date`, then sort based on the date objects etc.

```js
var months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];

function parse(dt) {
  var p = dt.replace(/(\,|\:)/g, ' ').split(/\s+/).filter((x) => {
    return x.trim().length > 0;
  });
  return new Date(p[2], months.indexOf(p[0]), p[1], p[3], p[4], p[5]);
}
var $scope = {}; // for demonstration ...

$scope.arr = [{
  test: 1,
  dt: 'March, 10 2016 14:55:00'
}, {
  test: 2,
  dt: 'February, 10 2013 14:25:00'
}, {
  test: 3,
  dt: 'August, 10 2015 14:55:00'
}];

$scope.arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return parse(b.dt) - parse(a.dt);
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify($scope.arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it via multiple ways. Either you change the format of the date to get back something like "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD" and then use orderBy to leverage the angular order by. Else you can loop and sort it manually with use of moment library.

Something like this

```
angular.forEach($scope.arr, function(o){ o.dt = new Date(o.dt); });
```

and then user orderBy for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of Angular Custom Filter and the orderBy filter can achieve this. This will also allow for further custom formatting.

Updated: Now shows adding new dates and ordering by any field.

```js
angular.module("app", ['core']);

angular.module("app").controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.arr = [{
    test: 1,
    dt: new Date('March, 10 2016 14:55:00')
  }, {
    test: 2,
    dt: new Date('February, 10 2013 14:25:00')
  }, {
    test: 3,
    dt: new Date('August, 10 2015 14:55:00')
  }];

  $scope.addDate = function() {
    var lastIndex = $scope.arr[$scope.arr.length - 1].test;
    $scope.arr.push({
      test: lastIndex + 1,
      dt: new Date($scope.newDate)
    });
  }

});

angular.module("core", []);
angular.module("core").filter("format", function(dateFilter) {
  return function(input) {
    if (input instanceof Date)
      return dateFilter(input, 'medium');
    return input;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newDate">
    <button ng-click="addDate()">Add Date</button>
    <br/>OrderBy Field:
    <input type="text" ng-model="orderField">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="(key,val) in arr[0]">
          {{key}}
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="o in arr | orderBy:orderField">
          <td ng-repeat="(key,val) in o">{{val | format}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```